# why image is getting distorted after reshape(64,64,3)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have written this code for distinguish cat  vs non cats in python as a case study on deep learning

```py
    import numpy as np
    import scipy
    import h5py
    from PIL import Image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from lr_utils import load_dataset

    def sigmoid(z):
        s=1/(1+np.exp(-z))
        return s

    def model(X,Y,testx,testy,alpha,iter,print_cost):
        w,b,costs=optimize(X,Y,iter,alpha,print_cost)
        #Predict Y for train and test sets of X
        Yhat_train = predict(w,b,X)
        Yhat_test = predict(w,b,testx)
        print(Yhat_test)
        #calculate accuracy
        acc_train=100-(np.mean(np.abs(Yhat_train-Y))*100)
        acc_test=100-(np.mean(np.abs(Yhat_test-testy))*100)
        print("Train accuracy is ",acc_train,"\nTest accuracy is ",acc_test)
          sol={"costs":costs,"w":w,"b":b,"Yhat_train":Yhat_train,"Yhat_test":Yhat_test,
        "Iterations":iter,"Learning_rate":alpha,"accuracy_train":acc_train,"accuracy_test":acc_test}
        return sol

    def optimize(X,Y,iter,alpha,print_cost):
        w = np.zeros((X.shape[0],1))
        b = 0.0
        m=X.shape[1]
        costs=[]
        for i in range(iter):
            A=sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X)+b)
            cost=-1/m*(np.dot( Y , np.log(A).T ) + np.dot( (1-Y) , np.log(1-A).T ))
            dz=A-Y
            dw=1/m*( np.dot(X , dz.T) )
            db=1/m*(np.sum(dz))
            w = w - alpha*dw
            b = b - alpha*db
            if i%100 == 0 :
                print("cost after iteration %i : %f" %(i,cost))
                costs.append(cost)
        return w, b, costs

    def predict(w,b,x):
        m = x.shape[1]
        Y_predict = np.zeros((1,m))
        w = w.reshape(x.shape[0],1)
        A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,x)+b)
        for i in range(m):
            if A[0,i] > 0.5:
                Y_predict[0,i] = 1
            else: Y_predict[0,i] = 0
        return Y_predict

    train_x,trainy,test_x,testy,classes=load_dataset()
    #To show the image in the x train data set with its corresponding value in y run the code below
    index = 1
    plt.imshow(test_x[index])
    plt.show()  # without this it wont show image in vscode
    print("y=",testy[:,index],"it's a ",classes[np.squeeze(testy[:,index])].decode("utf-8"))
    #data reshaping
    trainx=(train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[1]*train_x.shape[2]*train_x.shape[3],train_x.shape[0]))/255
    testx=(test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[1]*test_x.shape[2]*test_x.shape[3],test_x.shape[0]))/255
    print(trainx.shape,testx.shape)
    d=model(trainx,trainy,testx,testy,alpha=0.005,iter=2000,print_cost=True)
    index = 1
    img=(testx[:, index].reshape(64,64,3))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

Image of a cat after reshaping to its original size:

[image]
I am getting this output:

```
y= [1] it's a  cat
(12288, 209) (12288, 50)
cost after iteration 0 : 0.693147
cost after iteration 100 : 0.709726
cost after iteration 200 : 0.657712
cost after iteration 300 : 0.614611
cost after iteration 400 : 0.578001
cost after iteration 500 : 0.546372
cost after iteration 600 : 0.518331
cost after iteration 700 : 0.492852
cost after iteration 800 : 0.469259
cost after iteration 900 : 0.447139
cost after iteration 1000 : 0.426262
cost after iteration 1100 : 0.406617
cost after iteration 1200 : 0.388723
cost after iteration 1300 : 0.374678
cost after iteration 1400 : 0.365826
cost after iteration 1500 : 0.358532
cost after iteration 1600 : 0.351612
cost after iteration 1700 : 0.345012
cost after iteration 1800 : 0.338704
cost after iteration 1900 : 0.332664
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0.]]
Train accuracy is  91.38755980861244
Test accuracy is  34.0
```

But image of sample dataset before and after running the program is changing link is given below
also accuracy of test is 34% which is constant and irrelevant.

Comment: Can you add a standalone code to reproduce this issue? Add code that you use for image transformation that will accept the image and give a transformed image since that is your problem.

Comment: #original test_x shape : (209,64,64,3) reshape into (64*64*3,209)
    testx= 
 (test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[1]*test_x.shape[2]*test_x.shape[3],test_x.shape[0]))/255
    #after reshaping it again into (64,64,3) using code below, I am decoding a single 
    image at index no. 1
    img=(testx[:, 1].reshape(64,64,3)

Comment: Can you EDIT your question and post an executable minimal code focusing on your problem (image conversion) without all the network training issues?

Comment: You likely want to transpose the image `testx=np.transpose(test_x,(1,2,3,0)/255` Reshape is just another view on the same block of memory which can't work here.

Comment: then what should i do to show the image again?? @max9111

Comment: Solved the prob. fellows...it was my mistake of reshaping in a wrong format. i should have used :
trainx=(train_x.shape[0],train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[1]*train_x.shape[2]*train_x.shape[3]).T)/255
    testx=(test_x.shape[0],test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[1]*test_x.shape[2]*test_x.shape[3]).T)/255